# How to load Firebase database data in a in a synchronous way?

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to refactoring my android app to get a more tidy and understandable code. I'm using Firebase Database for the data persistence.

What I've done, it's to mostly refactor my classes into singletons, so I can easily use them in any other class.

This approach worked for the most classes (Firebase Storage Controller, GeoFire Controller, ecc), but I'm having trouble doing this on my Auth Controller because it needs to retrieve the user from the Auth system and from the Db too.

Below, some snippets of my code.

**The start activity**

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        AuthController.getInstance(new ResultListener<AuthController>(){
            @Override
            public void onResult(AuthController result) {
                AuthController authController = result;
                Intent intent;
                if ( authController.getUser() != null ) {
                    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                }
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**My auth controller**

```
public class AuthController {

    private static AuthController authController;
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public static AuthController getInstance(){
        if( authController == null ){
            getInstance(null);
            //TODO return authController
        }
        return authController;
    }

    public static void getInstance(final ResultListener<AuthController> authControllerResultListener) {
        initAuth(new ResultListener<AuthListener>() {
            @Override
            public void OnResult(AuthController authController) {
                AuthController.authController = authController;
                if(authControllerResultListener != null) {
                    authControllerResultListener.onResult(authController);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void initAuth(final ResultListener<AuthController> authListener) {
        final AuthController authController = new AuthController();
        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser authUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (authUser != null) {
                    String authUserId = authUser.getUid();
                    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    firebaseDatabase.getReference("users").child(authUserId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            authController.user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                            authListener.onResult(authController);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            authController.user = null;
                            authListener.onResult(authController);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    authController.user = null;
                    authListener.onResult(authController);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**My Abstract Activity** , this is extended by my other activities that needs to use the auth controller instance.

```
public abstract class MyAppActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected final AuthController authController = AuthController.getInstance();

}
```

**The Result Listener Interface**

```
public interface ResultListener<ResultType> {
    void onResult(ResultType result);
}
```

**So what I want to do is to get an instance of my auth controller that contains the user in a synchronous way**, but of course, the user has to be retrieved from firebase, so it seems hard to maintain it synchronous.

**Some tries**

I've tried using a new Thread and the join() that pause the main thread until the child thread finishes, but appears that the Firebase Listeners run on the main thread, so the code just get stuck during execution. And the same with an AsyncTask (see below).

*New Thread*

```
public static AuthController getInstance(){
    if( authController == null ){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initAuth(new ResultListener<AuthController>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(AuthController authController) {
                        AuthController.authController = authController;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.run();
        thread.join();
    }
    return authController;
}
```

*AsyncTask*

```
public static AuthController getInstance(){
    if( authController == null ){
        final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
        InitAuthAsync initAuthAsync = new AuthController().new InitAuthAsync();
        initAuthAsync.setResultListener(new ResultListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Void result) {
                semaphore.release();
            }
        });
        initAuthAsync.execute();
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return authController;
}

private class InitAuthAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private ResultListener<Void> resultListener;
    public void setResultListener(ResultListener<Void> resultListener) {
        this.resultListener = resultListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        initAuth(new ResultListener<AuthController>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(AuthController authController) {
                AuthController.authController = authController;
                resultListener.onResult(aVoid);
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: FriebaseAuth is already singleton. It seems you ironically had a spaghetti code to make it more tidy. What does AuthListener, ResultListener stands for? why do u need them?

Comment: ResultListener it is just an interface. I've update the question showing it. It needs to pass back the result value (the instantiated singleton with the user inside) once the task has completed. I need this to get back the current user object back to the main thread.
As said in the question: "it needs to retrieve the user from the Auth system and from the Db too"

Comment: The real question is how to wrap the initAuth method in a new thread/async task in a way that the firebase listeners are not executed on the main (sleeping) thread. As I can see, calling it from a new Thread it's not the solution. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is messy. Simple observer pattern will work in your case. Bu I recommend you to use [Eventbus Library](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/) which is lightweight and easy to use.

Comment: This does not explain how to deal with the requested multhitreading feature as longly explained in the question. The pattern I'm using is an MVC, so I need to get the user before an activity is created and store it in the singleton. So the Eventbus solution don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I post if anyone needs it. Take note that this is not the best architecture to use with firebase.

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        AuthController.initAuth(new ResultListener<AuthController>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(AuthController authController) {
                Intent intent;
                if ( authController.getUser() != null ) {
                    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainNavigationActivity.class);
                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                }
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }
        });

    }



}

public class AuthController {

    private static AuthController authController;
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public static AuthController getInstance() {
        if (authController == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The auth system is not initializet. Restart the app.");
        }
        return authController;
    }

    public static void initAuth(final ResultListener<AuthController> authListener) {
        final AuthController authController = new AuthController();
        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser authUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (authUser != null) {
                    String authUserId = authUser.getUid();
                    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    firebaseDatabase.getReference("users").child(authUserId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            authController.user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                            AuthController.authController = authController;
                            authListener.onResult(authController);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            authController.user = null;
                            AuthController.authController = authController;
                            authListener.onResult(authController);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    authController.user = null;
                    AuthController.authController = authController;
                    authListener.onResult(authController);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```